# VPN redirect user to specific IP and port

Tags: linux, vpn, port, ipsec

Hope you can point me in the right direction. I have this idea but need some advice and suggestions where to look at and how to do it (if it's possible)

I want my family members to connect to a VPN (linux server) using username and password, then I want to redirect each user to a specific port inside the same IP, let me describe it better:

user1 -> connects to VPN using user1 as username

Inside the VPN server I will redirect user1 to the IP and port 192.168.0.10:9800

Note: I am trying to use IPsec or OpenVPN, not sure which one, if you have a better suggestion, I am open to check it out. I may be retrieveing back containers with command lines linux only, RDP windows or VNC. I don't want to use a router.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible.

To do this with openVPN - set the OpenVPN config to give an IP to each user based the username. This is fairly straight forward using the  ifconfig-push directive (see https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Concepts-Addressing?

As you now know the clients IP you can then use iptables dnat rules to redirect all traffic from the client to the appropriate port with rules like (untested - probably needs tweeking)

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1  -j REDIRECT --to-port 9800
```